# Searching for a string over several columns in Excel, that is present in several rows and then combining information into a single row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, data-transfer

I have one spreadsheet with a series of work numbers - one on each row. Another spreadsheet has a series of treatments with work numbers spread over several rows and columns.

I want to search for a given works number in the second spreadsheet to find every row where it appears. I then hope to take every treatment and arrange them in a single row on the first sheet.

Ideal worksheet:
[image: Ideal worksheet]

Treatment sheet example:
[image: Treatment sheet example]

Worksheet example:
[image: Worksheet example]

Please let me know what functions i should look into or whether VBA is required here

Comment: Can you please check the screenshot of your ideal worksheet? It appears that work 5 should give `Heat   Cool` and work 4 should give `Cool`.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with a formula.

```
=TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1:$Z$1,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)-1,0),$B2)>0,Sheet2!$A:$A,"")) & "</s></t>", "//s"),""))
```

[image: Screenshot]
*<sup>Click on the image for a larger version.</sup>*

You'll need to update the references. In my mockup, `Sheet2` is the name of the sheet shown as "Treatment sheet example" in your question. Also, the range `Sheet2!$B$1:$Z$1` can be expanded to include additional columns if you think that sheet may need to grow larger. You can also make the range *smaller* to make the function run a little faster. Based on how your example sheets are setup, this formula should be in `C2` and then copied down.

Explanation:

- `OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$1:$Z$1,ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)-1,0)` lets us look at each row in the treatment sheet one at a time. It starts with the range `B1:Z1` and then offsets down on row at a time for as many rows as there are thanks to using `ROW(Sheet2!$A:$A)` as the input. That returns an array of all the row numbers. Subtract 1 and offset by that many to reference every row in `B:Z` one at a time.
- `IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(~),$B2)>0,Sheet2!$A:$A,""))` counts all the values (in those rows we're looking at one at a time) that are equal to the Work number on *this* sheet. If it finds at least one (`>0`), then it returns the Treatment from column `A` in `Sheet2`. Otherwise, it returns blank.
- `TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,IF(~))` joins all the Treatments it found into a single string separated by `</s><s>` which will make more sense in a minute. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c))
- `FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN(~) & "</s></t>", "//s")` is where the real magic happens. The function is not explicitly meant for this purpose but you can use it to turn a delimited string into an array instead. This lets us split up the string into individual cells. All the XML tags like `<t>` and `<s>` are to make the string look like XML. This is why we used `</s><s>` earlier. ([Reference](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filterxml-function-4df72efc-11ec-4951-86f5-c1374812f5b7))
- `IFERROR(FILTERXML(~),"")` will catch the error that happens with a Work value is never found in a sheet (`FILTERXML()` will be fed an invalid XML string) and turns it into a blank cell. In the screenshot, you can see I added a row at the bottom where this happens.
- `TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(FILTERXML(~)))` will turn the column of data given by `FILTERXML()` and turn it into a row of data.

Comment: This worked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this using Power Query, available in Office 365 and also Windows Excel 2010+

*I placed the two tables into **Tables**, named `work` and `treatment` in which case the worksheets are irrelevant.*

*You should be able to add/remove columns or rows to the Treatment table, and rows to the Work table, and the query should adjust when you refresh it.*

- Unpivot the Treatment table to create a two column table of Treatment and Work Number
- Join with the Work table
- Group the Joined table based on "Info" and "Work Number"

  - concatenating, then expanding into columns the treatments

*Please read the code comments for further information about the algorithm*

To use PQ

- Select some cell in on of your original tables
- `Data => Get&Transform => From Table/Range`
- When the PQ UI opens, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Examine any comments, and also the `Applied Steps` window, to better understand the algorithm and steps

```
let

//Read in the Work table
    SourceWrk= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="work"]}[Content],
//add index column for later sorting
    addIdx= Table.AddIndexColumn(SourceWrk,"IDX",0,1),

//Set data type
    workTable = Table.TransformColumnTypes(addIdx, {{"Info", type text},{"Work", Int64.Type}}),

//Read in the Treatment table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="treatment"]}[Content],

//dynamically type the columns
//  first column will be Text; other columns will be integers
    colXforms = {{"Treatment", type text}} & 
        List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),1), each {_,Int64.Type}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, colXforms),

//Unpivot and remove Attribute column to create two column table
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Treatment"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    treatmentTable = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),

//join the tables based on worknumber
    join= Table.Join(treatmentTable,"Value",workTable,"Work",JoinKind.FullOuter),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(join,{"Value"}),

//Group by Info and Work
//Then create the new columns for the treatments and IDX for sorting
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Info", "Work"}, {
        {"sortBy" , each [IDX]{0}},
        {"Treatment", each Text.Combine([Treatment],";"),type text}
        }),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Grouped Rows",{{"sortBy", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"sortBy"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Treatment", 
        Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv)),
    typeIt = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter", List.Transform(
        List.RemoveFirstN(Table.ColumnNames(#"Split Column by Delimiter"),2),each {_,type text}) )
in
    typeIt
```

[image]